# In Java unit tests, is it possible to include an assert statement within a loop?

Tags: java, junit

Here's my test:

```
@Test
public void randomDouble() {
    int Min = -1;
    int Max = 1;
    double r;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        r = Min + (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
        System.out.printf("%d %d: %.1f\n", Min, Max, r);
        assertTrue(Max < r && Max > r);
    }
}
```

It seems that the test returns after the first time the assertTrue statement within the loop is run. If I remove it, I get 5 results output. With it, I get only one.

I use this pattern in Python for fuzz testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's nothing to restrict asserts from being in loops.

some other points, though:

- the test will always fail (see next item for what you probably want)
- java has an assert in the language: `assert Min <= r && r <= Max : "bad range"`
- the "+1" in `((Max - Min) + 1)` seems wrong to me

Comment: oops - actually, i just fixed an error (changed `>=` to `<=`).  also, strictly speaking, i think you could use `r < Max` because `Math.random()` will never return exactly 1.0 (it's always less).

Answer (score 5):

The assertion fails on the first iteration; it can never pass (how can `r` be both bigger **and** smaller than `Max`?).

Comment: Egad. So preoccupied with assuming Java is out to thwart me, I missed the obvious. The output even looked correct to me! Thanks for indulging me.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you change the assertion to `assertTrue(Min < r && Max > r);`, which seems to be what is intended, the test still frequently fails on the first iteration: the "+1" in  `r = Min + (Math.random() * ((Max - Min)+1));` is wrong.